# d3: Animate bar chart transforming into pie chart, like Heer and Robertson do?

Tags: animation, d3.js

How difficult would it be to use d3 to create animations like those found in [this study](http://vis.berkeley.edu/papers/animated_transitions/)?  In particular, animating a bar chart into a donut chart into a pie chart smoothly?

The idea I had was to start by replacing the "rect"s in the bar chart with "path" elements formed fromn d3.svg.arc -- using an arc with a huge radius, but only taking wedge of it, so that it was looks almost like a "rect" but slightly curved.  Once that replacement is done, then you can animate the radius and angle of the arc in the "path" element and move it into the donut shape that you want.  The final transition from donut to pie would be trivial, simply animating the innerRadius.

However, I'd like to know if there is a better way to accomplish this, or perhaps some plugins that have already been written?

Comment: [This example](http://d3-example.herokuapp.com/examples/showreel/showreel.html) has (almost) the transition you want.

Comment: Indeed it does!  Thank you.  You should add your comment as an answer.  I may leave it up a day or two just to see if anyone else has input, but that's what I was looking for.

Comment: For anybody else that  might be looking: http://jsfiddle.net/amitaviv99/x6RWs/42/ from this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16326978/d3-transitioning-from-bar-to-pie-and-back could be helpful

Comment: A important distinction between the transitions used in @sarul's links and the interaction suggested in the study is that the study recommends that the bar charts map to the arc lengths of each slice in the pie. In links from  sarul's comment, the bar chart lengths are mapped to pie slice lengths.

Answer (score 8):

[This example](http://d3-example.herokuapp.com/examples/showreel/showreel.html) has (almost) the transition that you're looking for.