# d3 transitioning from bar to pie and back

Tags: animation, coffeescript, d3.js

[LIVE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/fresheyeball/52TNQ/)

So I have this notion that all single axis data should be allowed to be displayed in all the basic ways; and at the very least from a pie to a bar. Ideally this would be an animated transition, but thats were the difficulty comes in.

Getting a pie chart to work is easy enough, as is getting a bar chart. Here is what I have so far:

```
# fields
width   = 750
height  = width/2
margin  = 20
radius  = (height-(margin*2))/2

# helpers
pie     = d3.layout.pie().value (d) -> d 
arc     = d3.svg.arc()
    .outerRadius(radius)
    .innerRadius(radius/4)
x       = d3.scale.linear().domain([0, 100]).range [0, width]

$http.get('/Classification_Top_10_by_Count.json').success (data) ->

    percents = (parseFloat item.Percent for item in data).sort d3.ascending

    svg      = d3.select('#svgStage').append('svg')         
        .attr('width', width+(margin*2))
        .attr('height', height+(margin*2))

    svg.data([percents])

    g = svg.append('g')
        .attr('transform', "translate(#{radius},#{radius})")

    paths   = g.selectAll 'path'

    paths.data(pie).enter().append('path')
        .attr('d', arc)

    toBars = ->
        g.selectAll('path').transition().duration(2000) 
            .attr 'd', (d, index) ->
                # this is over complex because I was playing with it.
                cord = 
                    tl : [0,          index*20]
                    tr : [d.value*20, index*20]
                    br : [d.value*20, index*20-20]
                    bl : [0,          index*20-20]
                oCord = [
                    cord.tl
                    cord.tr 
                    cord.br 
                    cord.bl
                ]
                "M #{oCord[0][0]}, #{oCord[0][2]}
                A 0, 0 0 0, 0 #{oCord[1][0]}, #{oCord[1][3]}
                L #{oCord[2][0]}, #{oCord[2][4]}
                A 0, 0 0 0, 0 #{oCord[3][0]}, #{oCord[3][5]}
                Z"
```

Obviously for this to work its got to be path element to path element, and the transition is working now. Problem is it looks like crap. The moment it starts it looks garbled, until it over and becomes decent bar chart.

I've been looking at this : http://d3-example.herokuapp.com/examples/showreel/showreel.html
Which demonstrates a bar transitioning to a donut in much the way I would like. Looking at the source code, this is accomplished through a custom tween. (view source line 518)

Now I'm in over my head. What is going on here? How can I get this transition to work? Has anyone else out there dealt with this problem?

---

**UPDATE**

Just to be clear, below illustrations the intention of my transition abit more clearly.

[image]

---

Bounty clarity. I added a bounty to this question because I need an explanation of what was going wrong. Superboggly did that, so he got the bounty. However Amit Aviv's approach is superior, so I accept his answer as the most correct. I have also +1ed both.

Comment: I can see only until line 660 in the HTML...am I supposed to be looking at another file instead?

Comment: you are right. Its 518,

Comment: Aside from any technical issues, how would you animate from a wedge to a bar? Donut to bar is easy since the donut "wedges" are really just curved bars, so all you need to do is straighten them out. A wedge doesn't naturally lend itself to such a transform. If you add an intermediate step pie -> donut -> bar does that help you achieve the effect you're after?

Comment: @ColinYoung its not impossible to go from a wedge to a bar, as in d3 wedges are just donuts with a hole size of zero. What I need is help understanding how to implement the transition, both from a d3 framework perspective and a math perspective.

Comment: @Fresheyeball your demo shows the donut switching back to full wedges as soon as the animation starts. The showreel example appears to (I wish I could slow it down) animate the bars by changing the radius from some large value (effectively infinite) down to the target radius while simultaneously adjusting the angle. To get a pie, you could animate the inner radius to a target value of zero. I think it's really just a geometry problem. I'd suggest  pencil and paper and drawing out a few frames of the desired animation.

Comment: @ColinYoung I understand. Open the console, d3 fails to parse, I think thats more it.

Comment: @Fresheyeball There's only a couple parsing errors there :)

Comment: @ColinYoung ultimately once I can get a smooth not broken transition, then I will worry about the finer details of how the pie 'unfurels'

Comment: A rough but fairly simple approach: http://jsfiddle.net/superboggly/RLqht/2/

Comment: @Superboggly I really like the direction you went, but I still don't understand why what you did works and why what I did does not. If you can wrap that in an answer, it would be most awesome of you.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here is my take: http://jsfiddle.net/amitaviv99/x6RWs/42/

My approach was to approximate both the arcs & bars using cubic bezier curves, with the exact same number of control points. The code is somewhat complicated, and need some work. But the result is quite smooth.

Here is an excerpt (SO requires..)

```
var bezierArc = function(radiusIn, radiusOut, startAngle, endAngle){
    var arcIn = makeCompArc(radiusIn, startAngle, endAngle);
    var arcIOut = makeCompArc(radiusOut, startAngle, endAngle);
    var lines = makeBezierDoubleLine(radiusIn, radiusOut, startAngle, endAngle);
    var path = [arcIn, lines[0], arcOut, lines[1]].join(' ');

    return path;
}
```

Answer (score 9):

D3 does a pretty good job of interpolating between paths, but it was having trouble with your original before and after path so instead of taking over the whole tweening process myself I thought maybe we could come up with better paths to make the job easier for D3. My [result](http://jsfiddle.net/superboggly/RLqht/3/).

The first thing is to look at the svg arc path element. It basically goes like this:

```
A rx,ry a f1,f2 x,y
```

you can read the details [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/paths.html#PathDataEllipticalArcCommands). This will draw an arc from wherever you are (previous final coordinate) to the coordinates x,y. But the things to focus on are that the first two numbers are the implied ellipse's radii and the last part before the end coordinates, that I've marked *f1,f2*, are flags and so not interpolate-able.

So the main weirdness in the transition from your code is because you are trying to interpolate between

A rx,ry, 0 0,**1**

A 0,0 0 0,**0**

You will immediately see a smoother transition if you set your end-path to A0,0 0 0,1 in the one case.

To make the pieces fit together a bit better I animated the pie's inner radius so that the segments looked more like the bars but curved, then I let D3 figure out the curve-to-bar transition but without switching the arc flag. Then you want the bars to have flat ends. The path will have a flatter arc if you increase your implied ellipses radii! So I simply used 100,100. My final transition-to path for the bars looks like:

```
"M " + oCord[0][0] + "," + oCord[0][1] + 
"A100,100 0 0,1 " + oCord[1][0] + "," + oCord[1][1] + 
"L " + oCord[2][0] + "," + oCord[2][1] + 
"A100,100 0 0,0 " + oCord[3][0] + "," + oCord[3][1] + 
"Z";
```

Then To actually, properly, flatten the endpoints I have a second transition (they run serially) to zero the Arc segments of the path. I suspect there is a better way to do this kind of cleanup with D3 transitions, but a transition with duration 0 also works.

To get the reverse to work nicely I set the paths to the flattened-arc-curves from above. Having the large radius and correct flags means the D3-computed transition back to the doughnut chart works well. Then I simply animate the inner radius back out.

Comment: your solution works great. but when i update the values of the array with a big disparity [2,3,24] for example, d3 spits out a invalid path during transition - jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/geoe5sy7/1/ . Any clue why d3 cant transition smoothly ? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Looking at the console output I think the scientific notation is confusing SVG. When you build your path string make sure to format the numbers so they are regular floats. You are getting very small numbers that can probably be replaced by 0.